# applying style to any level under a div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

here is my CSS:

```
div.leftNav 
{
}

div.leftNav a:link { color: black; }
div.leftNav a:visited { color: black; }
div.leftNav a:active { color: black; }
div.leftNav a:focus { color: black; }
```

the issue is that the `a` tag is not immediately under the `div` that has the class `leftNav`, it is a number of levels down and at times within other elements, like `span`s.  My goal is to effect all a links under one `div`, how do I do that?

Comment: If you put a space between selectors it *will* select **all** descendants of specified type. Maybe you're not seeing wanted behavior because there's a more specific rule overwriting the ones you posted? (See this [handy W3 overview](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), and this on the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators))

Comment: What problem are you seeing? The code you've posted should do exactly what you're describing.

Comment: ok but still you can have unique identifier for that and use div.lefNav #id_name

Answer (score 1):

This will select any anchor element  within .leftNav and give it a black color.

```
.leftNav a { color: black; }
```

You should not need to select by element (div.leftNav), which is kind of bad practice since it makes your selector break as soon as you assign class .leftNav to any other element than a div. Neither do you need to select each pseudo-class of a (a:link, a:focus etc) since they will be overwritten by the selector above if you haven't given them a specific global styling (a:visited, a:link etc), which also is sort of bad practice if you have to overwrite that global rule on several places in your css.

If you are, however, styling links globally using a:visited and a:link for example, assign them a class (such as .link) instead of selecting them by element, and style them that way:

```
.link:link { color: blue; }
.link:visited { color: green; }
```

This means that you won't have to override styling for links that should look different, just do not assign those links the class of .link.